# How can I calculate if a Date Object is closer to one or another Date

Tags: javascript, date

I am building a calendar where people can select a range of days from a visual calendar.

Clicking on a date will select it as a "from" or "to" date. For example, if I click on 1januari and 5 January. 1 January will be the "from" date while 5 January will be the "to" date. Easy right?

Now the thing is if a user clicks on a new date, I will need to update the current "from" and "to" dates. Using

`stringToDate(date.dateTime) > stringToDate(this.state.fromDate)`

lets me know if the incoming date is later then the current "from date" with I can use to change the current "to" date to the incoming Date because 7 January comes after 5 January with "must" mean the user wanted to update their "to" date.

A similar function does the same thing for the "from" date. This works great and all but this means that users can't select a "from" date that comes later than their original "from" date.

What I want to achieve is the following: Calculate if the incoming date is closer to the "from" date or the "to" date. So if a user starts with 1 and 5 January and clicks on 2 January I can assume that he wants to update his "from" date.

My current function looks like this:

```
handleFromDateSelected(date) {
    let updatedFromDate = '';
    let updatedToDate = '';

    if (this.state.fromDate) {
        if (stringToDate(date.dateTime) > stringToDate(this.state.fromDate)) {
            updatedFromDate = this.state.fromDate;
            updatedToDate = date.dateTime;
        } else {
            updatedFromDate = date.dateTime;
            updatedToDate = this.state.fromDate;
        }
    } else {
        updatedFromDate = date.dateTime;
    }

    this.setState({
        fromDate: updatedFromDate,
        toDate: updatedToDate,
    });
}
```

Comment: This will be making assumptions of user's choices. I am a user, I pick 1st january (from), then 5th january (to). Then, I change my mind and decide my "to" date will be 2nd january, then my "from" will become 2nd january and my "to" remains 5th january. This wasn't what I wanted.

Comment: Why not using 2 dates picker, a "from" and a "to" ?

Comment: or reset the the from & to everytime he picks a new one

Comment: Here is the thing, the designers want 2 calendars next to each other. With works great but they must be 1 month apart, for example Jan & Feb. If a user wants to select 2 dates from the same month they will need to use the same input. Just like the date picker from: https://www.booking.com/

Comment: This datepicker works differently. you can change the from or to depending on which date you've clicked

Comment: You are right, just saw it now. I however cannot go with that solution, my calendar alo stays open with is a big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to check from which date the new one is closed, which is, in my opinion not a good choice, you can convert all 3 dates (from, to and new) to timestamp and compare the absolute difference. The lowest one means this is closer to the new one.

in example, let's assume `dateFrom`, `dateTo` and `newDate` are date objects :

```
//Returns true if newDate is closer to dateFrom
function isFromDateCloser(dateFrom, dateTo, newDate)
{
    timeStampFrom = dateFrom.getTime();
    timeStampTo = dateTo.getTime();
    timeStampNew = newDate.getTime();

    return (Math.abs(timeStampFrom - timeStampNew) < Math.abs(timeStampTo - timeStampNew));
}

if (isFromDateCloser(dateFrom, dateTo, newDate))
    dateFrom = newDate;
else
    dateTo = newDate;
```

In that example, I've arbitrary choosen that if new date is strictly between both dates, the new date will be dateTo. If you prefer the that the from become the new date, replace in the return `<` by `<=`

Comment: Thanks for your working answer, I have however, convinced the designers to let me use two different inputs, just like Booking.com. This will make things a lot easier.

Comment: This is indeed a better option rather than guessing what the user has in mind

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
 var firstDate = new Date(date.dateTime);
 var secondDate = new Date(this.state.fromDate)
          if (firstDate.getTime() > secondDate .getTime()){
  // do something here 
  }
```

Comment: This just checks if the incoming date is later then the current date. This is what I currently have working.